# Rails generate scaffold is auto populating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I ran generate scaffold and 12 records on my view were filled with 'MyString' data. How can stop the generator from auto populating my records?

ID     Account       Name      Created At
1                    MyString
2                    MyString
3                    MyString
4                    MyString
...
12                   MyString

Comment: That's not a behavior you would normally see. Can you give an example of how you encountered this result? What generator command did you run? What do the resulting migration/model/controller/view look like? In which file did these unexpected strings appear?

Comment: @Jonah, The command used was 'rails g scaffold BenefitPlans benefit_id:integer name:string description:text --skip-stylesheets'. 12 records in each model appear after I run migrate.

Comment: I can't answer this without more information. As I guess I would look into if you loaded test fixtures into your development database but that's pure speculation. Please update your question to hopefully get a more precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your fixtures, if you look at these files more closely they will have "Mystrings" in them. And/Or delete in testhelper your fixtures.

Comment: Please do add some explanation